# How to use HTTPS canonical link tag in Blogger blog?

Tags: https, canonical-url, blogger

Look out, Google official security blog - http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com

Above blog forced user to visit https link (without using any kind of JS), but normal Blogger blog serve both content over HTTP as well as HTTPS (Sometimes, I think, Google official blog have more functionality then normal Blogger). Well, it is kind of duplicate issue, but we can solve, if we get proper [canonical link tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en).

Look out source page of that blog, you will see HTTPS in `canonical` link tag.

```
<link href='https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/' rel='canonical'/>
```

But most of all bloggers including me, when enable HTTPS, then we see HTTP in `canonical` link tag, but we want to use HTTPS in `canonical` link tag.

So, is there any way to get current permalink of Blogger pages/posts with HTTPS link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blogger beta now giving free SSL to custom domain which fix https links automatically in canonical link tag. To do that

1. Go to [draft.blogger.com](https://draft.blogger.com), you can see upcoming release there.
2. Then go to settinig > basic and enable https availability.
   [image]
3. Now go back to your main blogger.com dashboard, and you will see same option there, but it may take few minutes(for me 2 minute) to enable it on your main dashboard, because blogger automatically register SSL certificate for your custom domain.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Google Official Security Blog, and the gadgets in the sidebar.  Look at the links in the blog - where do they lead?

The Google blog has very few links - and **all of them are HTTPS**.

Now, look at the typical Blogger blog.  They'll have gadgets in the sidebar, that they get from God knows where - and links to blogs and websites that are not on HTTPS.

Blogger is not the only major publishing platform to be just getting into SSL.  All of the non SSL gadgets and links, that will be all over the typical Blogger blog, will generate "Mixed Content" alerts.

The typical blog reader, surfing to a Blogger blog with non SSL gadgets and links, and forced into HTTPS: mode, will see the "Mixed Content" alerts, and will bail.

> I'm not surfing there, again!

The bottom line - Blogger cannot go to full SSL, because the content of the blogs will freak the readers - because other blogs and websites are not there.

Blogger Engineering stated explicitly that the canonical URL for the blog - or for any post - will be "http:" - not "https:" - because they want our readers to have the option to use "http:".  And that, because their content best supports "http:".

Your readers deserve the option.

If you really don't want your readers to have the option to use "http:" to access your blog, here's where you start.

> <b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>

That's the reference to the standard blog header, which contains the canonical tag - and the rest of the header content.

What's the current supported solution, here, for overriding header content?

Comment: The OP seems to be asking if there's a way to use a canonical link with HTTPS. Can you edit this to better address that?

Comment: @nitecruzr . Just make one new blogger blog, and enable https from setting menu. Now look out source page, you will see http in canonical link tag. It is not about gadgets or mixed content.